# Why I get $http undefined inside controller using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

What's wrong on this?

```
var modulo = angular.module('SWAApp', []);
modulo.controller('SWAAllocationController', ['$scope','$http', function RunSWAAllocation($scope,$http) {
    $scope.LaunchAllocation = function RunSWAAllocation($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/MP3_SIOP/WS/SWAService.svc/PostSWAAllocation')
        .success(function (data) {
            pvt_BindHeaderData($scope, data);
            alert("SWA Allocation OK");
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            alert("Si è verificato un errore nel dei dati!")
        });
    }
}]);
```

and

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="SWAAllocationController">
        <button type="button" ng-click="LaunchAllocation()">Run Allocation </button> ...
```

This give me $http undefined (and also $scope)

Thank a lot for your help.

PS: Sorry if I miss something or made something wrong, this is my first question and I'm not skilled on AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove *$scope and $http* from method `$scope.LaunchAllocation`.

$scope and $http are dependencies that u imported in controller already and no need to add as parameters in method. You can directly use it. If you are using in method as parameters and passing nothing when you call it (from ng-click), obviously they both will be undefined.

```
$scope.LaunchAllocation = function() {
        $http.get('/MP3_SIOP/WS/SWAService.svc/PostSWAAllocation')
        .success(function (data) {
            pvt_BindHeaderData($scope, data);
            alert("SWA Allocation OK");
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            alert("Si è verificato un errore nel dei dati!")
        });
    }
```

Also you don't need to put the function name after **function**. You are calling the function `$scope.LaunchAllocation` and not the other one. So it actually not needed

Answer (score 0):

I believe `$http` in that context is `undefined`

```
$scope.LaunchAllocation = function RunSWAAllocation($scope, $http) {
```

replace with this ...

```
$scope.LaunchAllocation = function RunSWAAllocation() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace

```
$scope.LaunchAllocation = function RunSWAAllocation($scope, $http)
```

with

```
$scope.LaunchAllocation = function RunSWAAllocation()
```